# Navigation Drawer toolbar not showing when profile activity shows up

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

My question is that my navigation drawer toolbar hides behind the decoration of the profile activity. i looked through question like that and the only possible solutions i got were to change constraint layout to linear layout but without the constraints, i dont know how the inverted curved rectangle will hold up. Please help!
profileActivity.xml
`

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#E1E1E1"
android:backgroundTint="#E1E1E1"
tools:context=".ProfileActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/top_bkg"
                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-205dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/Pic"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/outline_person_24"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                        app:civ_border_width="3dp"
                        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="130dp"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="120dp" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="328dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/white_bkg"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/Name"
                            android:layout_width="15dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="@string/nameLbl"
                            android:textColor="#182693"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/nmTxt"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                            android:textColor="#182693"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                        android:background="#D9D9D9" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/Mobile"
                            android:layout_width="15dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="@string/mobileLbl"
                            android:textColor="#182693"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/mobileTxt"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"

                            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                            android:textColor="#182693"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                        android:background="#D9D9D9" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/eMail"
                            android:layout_width="15dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="@string/e_mailLbl"
                            android:textColor="#182693"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            tools:ignore="TextSizeCheck" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/emText"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"

                            android:text=""
                            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                            android:textColor="#182693"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>


            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

my content layout file with shares layout on multiple pages from the navigation drawer :
`

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

>
     <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white"/>
  </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/activityContainer"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/appBarLayout"
    />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`

my drawer_base activity
`

```
  <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".DrawerBaseActivity"
tools:openDrawer="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>
 <include layout="@layout/content_layout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

/>
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/main_drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/main_drawer_menu"
    />

  </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>`
```

profile activity.java
`
package com.example.login_page_simple;

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
//earlier it was public class ProfileActivity extends drawerbaseactivity

public class ProfileActivity extends DrawerBaseActivity{
ActivityProfileBinding activityProfileBinding;
TextView etRole, etEmail, etExId, etAdId, etName, etMob;
ImageView imageView;
SharedPrefMANAGER sharedPrefMANAGER;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activityProfileBinding = ActivityProfileBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    allocateActivityTitle("Profile");
    setContentView(activityProfileBinding.getRoot());

    etName = findViewById(R.id.nmTxt);
    etMob = findViewById(R.id.mobileTxt);
  //etRole= findViewById(R.id.roleTxt);
    etEmail = findViewById(R.id.emText);
    //etExId=findViewById(R.id.exIdTxt);
    //etAdId=findViewById(R.id.adminTxt);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.Pic);
    sharedPrefMANAGER = new SharedPrefMANAGER(getApplicationContext());

    etName.setText(sharedPrefMANAGER.getObj().getName());
    etMob.setText(sharedPrefMANAGER.getObj().getMobile());
    //etRole.setText(sharedPrefMANAGER.getObj().getRole());
    etEmail.setText(sharedPrefMANAGER.getObj().getEmail());
    //etExId.setText(sharedPrefMANAGER.getObj().getExam_id());
    //etAdId.setText(sharedPrefMANAGER.getObj().getAdmin_id());
    
    });`
```

Comment: what worked instead was adding an icon to XML file and including this function in the corresponding activity: private void setVariable() {
        bckBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

Answer (score 0):

you can try wrapping the entire layout in a CoordinatorLayout and using the AppBarLayout to create the toolbar like below and access it on onCreate in your activity file like this -

Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E1E1E1"
    android:backgroundTint="#E1E1E1"
    tools:context=".ProfileActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/top_bkg"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

          

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!-- Your existing content goes here -->

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: this should work i guess like the way you need, let me know

Comment: it didnt help, i see what you are doing is introducing a separate toolbar but I want the one with the navigation drawer attached which is hidden behind the constraint layout.